# Nested form and belong_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 3 models in my rails app:

event
location
group

each event and group have one location.

I have following models and associations:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
    belongs_to :location    
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

---

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups
    has_many :events
end
```

---

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :location
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

I searched on SO and google but i was not able to found correct answer for "how to use nested attributes on belongs_to side" specially for Rails 4.

So please tell me how i can use it or any other best way to define above association.
thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed I want to add accepts_nested_attributes_for :location on belong_to side, what is the best way to do that ?